# uuid.py Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-2to3

I've used 2to3 to pass uuid.py from Python 2 to 3. However, now it gives me another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uuid.py", line 473, in <module>
    NAMESPACE_DNS = UUID('6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8')
  File "uuid.py", line 128, in __init__
    int = int(hex, 16)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The code from a few lines before 128:

```
def __init__(self, hex=None, bytes=None, fields=None, int=None,
                       version=None):
        r"""Create a UUID from either a string of 32 hexadecimal digits,
        a string of 16 bytes as the 'bytes' argument, a tuple of six
        integers (32-bit time_low, 16-bit time_mid, 16-bit time_hi_version,
        8-bit clock_seq_hi_variant, 8-bit clock_seq_low, 48-bit node) as
        the 'fields' argument, or a single 128-bit integer as the 'int'
        argument.  When a string of hex digits is given, curly braces,
        hyphens, and a URN prefix are all optional.  For example, these
        expressions all yield the same UUID:

        UUID('{12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678}')
        UUID('12345678123456781234567812345678')
        UUID('urn:uuid:12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678')
        UUID(bytes='\x12\x34\x56\x78'*4)
        UUID(fields=(0x12345678, 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x12, 0x34, 0x567812345678))
        UUID(int=0x12345678123456781234567812345678)

        Exactly one of 'hex', 'bytes', 'fields', or 'int' must be given.
        The 'version' argument is optional; if given, the resulting UUID
        will have its variant and version number set according to RFC 4122,
        overriding bits in the given 'hex', 'bytes', 'fields', or 'int'.
        """

        if [hex, bytes, fields, int].count(None) != 3:
            raise TypeError('need just one of hex, bytes, fields, or int')
        if hex is not None:
            hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
            hex = hex.strip('{}').replace('-', '')
            if len(hex) != 32:
                raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
            int = int(hex, 16)
```

The last one is 128.

The first one is 97.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you post the whole code causing the problem. Also, don't use python keywords as variable names, choose other names instead of `int` and `hex`

Comment: Do you mean the whole `uuid.py` file?

Comment: The part that caused the problem. according to the traceback, a few lines before **line 128**

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: We need to see a few lines before that as well. How is int defined?

Comment: I mean a few lines before the: if [hex, ...

Comment: Sorry, now it's fixed.

Comment: Ok, just don’t use keyword for your variable names.

Comment: They're not keywords actually, otherwise you wouldn't be able to assign to them. They're actually builtins. But yes, don't assign to Python builtin names. BTW in the future, please provide a [mre]. I was able to reproduce the issue in [3 lines](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/30ed543e8fe41c9dd5e397354fd2a028).

Comment: Sorry, I confuse my terms easily.